# Get number of records before specific column value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get few records before a certain value in column. I saw this link [Get number of rows before and after a certain index value in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819671/get-number-of-rows-before-and-after-a-certain-index-value-in-pandas) but this has the solution based on index. I want to implement it on column value.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['abc','bcd','string1','string2','jkl','opq']}
dfx=pd.DataFrame(d)

v1="string1"
history=pd.DataFrame()
history=history.append(dfx.loc[dfx['col1']==v1],ignore_index=True)
history
```

This code gives me only the matched record.

```
col1
string1
```

I want:

```
col1
abc
bcd
string1
```

I want records before that as well. I am sorry I just started to learn about slicing. I am stuck.

Comment: Can you show the expected output and a minimal input? Consider coming up with a [MCVE]

Comment: @HarvIpan I edited it. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.idxmax()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to get the first occurance of `string1` and then slice to that position.

```
history = dfx.iloc[:(dfx['col1']==v1).idxmax()+1]
```

Output:

```
    col1
0   abc
1   bcd
2   string1
```

Comment: Great. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help. @amy

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that your index is continuous and ascending. You could do `.reset_index()` if it isn't continuous. It also finds the first occurance of `v1` in col1. Hope this helps:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['abc','bcd','string1','string2','jkl','opq']}
dfx=pd.DataFrame(d)

v1="string1"
history=pd.DataFrame()

# Get the FIRST index where col1 is equal to v1
v1_idx = dfx[dfx.col1 == v1].index[0]

# Make a list of indices to select 
select_idx = np.arange(0,v1_idx+1)

# Take subset and reset index
history=dfx.loc[dfx.index.isin(select_idx)].reset_index(drop=True)
history
```